# Discrepancy in the measured metrics in my segmentation models

Tags: pytorch, image-segmentation

I’ve trained my image segmentation models using SegmentationModelsPytorch. Three annotators marked up objects. All pixels that were voted as an object pixel by two annotators were marked as the pixels of the object. Each picture was divided in crops, enriched with crops with target pixels (reflection and rotations by 90/180/270 degrees).

Key lines of code:

```
loss = smp.utils.losses.BCELoss() + smp.utils.losses.DiceLoss()
metrics = [smp.utils.metrics.IoU(threshold=torch.tensor(0.3))]
```

and

```
for i in range(0, EPOCHS):
    train_logs = train_epoch.run(train_loader)
    valid_logs = valid_epoch.run(valid_loader)
    is_best = max_score < valid_logs['iou_score']
    model_name = ''
    if max_score < valid_logs['iou_score']:
        max_score = valid_logs['iou_score']
        model_name = f'{dt}_{i}_score_{round(max_score, 5)}.pth'
        model_full_path = path.join('models', model_name)
        torch.save(model, model_full_path)
```

Somehow I get Intersection over Union (IoU) of 0.19, 0.28, 0.20 for pairs of dermatologists.
Model reports IoU = 0.87 in the best case in training.
When measuring IoU of the prediction with the ground truth on the same test set I get IoU = 0.81

So, how is it possible that averaging yields such an improvement (from 0.19-0.28) to 0.87?
Why does the actual measured IoU on the *same* test set differs from the IoU, reported by the model during training (0.87 vs 0.81)?

You can see the training code https://pastebin.com/Vf2By09U
And the measurement code https://pastebin.com/wtD4haej